# "Input String was not in correct format" - release rejected in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

I am hosting a website on Visual Studio Team Services. I want to manage releases, using the release tab to upload my files over `SFTP` using the `Upload * with cURL` build step. However, when I do this, I get this error:

> Input String was not in correct format
>
> Deployment on this environment was cancelled.

NB: Pre-deployment approval passed.

What does this message mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: What values did you provide for the parameters?

Comment: @DanielMann `Files: *` then just my password, username and `url: ssh.mydomain.co.uk`

Comment: Can you share the entire logs?

Comment: This could happen if the input build is not available or accessible. (We are improving the error messages in this area.)

Comment: @VijayMachiraju OK, thanks. So how should I set up this release step to upload all the files over sftp?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "Files" from "*" to "**\*".